# Как убрать сообщение в консоли? Python

Tags: python, pyrogram

или день. Делаю в телеграмме бота, использую модуль "pyrogram". Данный модуль беспрерывно спамит в консоль. Вопрос, как убрать этот бесконечный спам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю, за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в ваш код (снизить уровень логирования) :

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Добрый человек.